# Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value in flutter

Tags: flutter, visual-studio, dart

I hope you are well, I will give you a bit of context about my problem...
I really don't know why this error happens and I've seen many similar publications but they haven't worked for me.
I'm new to flutter and I'm working on an app, but when the user wants to log out, the app crashes and shows the following error:

```
E/flutter (12659): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value
E/flutter (12659): #0      StatefulElement.state
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4999
E/flutter (12659): #1      Navigator.of
package:flutter/…/widgets/navigator.dart:2543
E/flutter (12659): #2      Navigator.pushReplacement
package:flutter/…/widgets/navigator.dart:2105
E/flutter (12659): #3      MainCoordinator.logoutNavigation
package:domicilios/…/MainCoordinator/MainCoordinator.dart:62
E/flutter (12659): #4      UserActions.signOut.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>
package:domicilios/…/View/ProfileTab.dart:222
E/flutter (12659): <asynchronous suspension>


This is the code that generates this error, I hope you can help me, thank you very much for your attention.

this is the class:

extension UserActions on _ProfileTabState {
  void signOut(BuildContext context) {
    AlertView.showAlertDialog(
        model: AlertViewModel(
            context,
            const AssetImage('assets/logout.png'),
            'Cierre de sesión en curso',
            "¿Desear salir de la sesión actual?",
            'Cerrar sesión',
            "Cancelar", () {
      _profileTabViewModel
          .signOut()
          .then((value) => coordinator.logoutNavigation(context: context));
    }, () {
      Navigator.pop(context);
    }));
  }
} 

That's how I call it in the code:
onTap: () => signOut(context),
```

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely due to the `widget` being `unmounted` before navigating.

You can check if the `widget` is mounted before navigating.

```
if (mounted) {
  _profileTabViewModel.signOut().then((value) {
    if (mounted) {
      coordinator.logoutNavigation(context: context);
    }
  });
}
```

Also,

```
if(mounted){
  Navigator.pop(context);
}
```

Comment: And depending on how `.signOut()` is implemented, you may want to test for `mounted` again after that Future returns (so before `coordinator.logoutNavigation(context: context)`

Comment: You are right, added that.

Comment: it means, user is still called after you have logged out and nullified it

Comment: Hello, sorry for not having responded before, the suggestion you gave me is already poor and the following happens, the application no longer stops but the screen after closing the session remains frozen and does not return me to login. But if I restart the application, it lets me know that the session is closed.